# Expected identifier or (

Tags: iphone

I am working on a web browser app but at the moment I am stuck with the error:"Expected identifier or '('" and I don't know what to do. Here is the code where the error is shown:

```
{:here is the error
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}
```

Help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

I don't know what other code I am supposed to give you so here is the whole code in the ViewController.m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *back;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *refresh;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *stop;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *forward;

- (void)loadRequestFromString:(NSString*)urlString;

{ *HERE IS THE ERROR:EXPECTED IDENTIFIER OR '('*
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}

@end

@implementation ViewController ***HERE IS A WARNING SAYING:METHOD DEFINITION FOR 'LOADREQUESTFROMSTRING:'NOT FOUND***

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any `enter code here`additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self loadRequestFromString:@"http://www.apple.com/startpage/"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Where is that error being displayed?

Comment: Show more code (context), as there is nothing wrong with the code you have posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have implementation code in your interface

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *back;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *refresh;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *stop;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *forward;

// This is a private interface and doesn't need the below line ever.
// If you want this public then add it to the interface in the .h file.
- (void)loadRequestFromString:(NSString*)urlString;

*****************************************************************************
// This is implementation code and shouldn't be here. 
// This belongs in the implementation not the interface
{ *HERE IS THE ERROR:EXPECTED IDENTIFIER OR '('*
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}
*****************************************************************************
@end
```

In your implementation `@implementation` add

```
@implementation ViewController
// Your other code such as viewDidLoad etc

// Adding this method to the implementation will also get rid of the warning
// ***HERE IS A WARNING SAYING:METHOD DEFINITION FOR 'LOADREQUESTFROMSTRING:'NOT FOUND***
// As it will now be implemented but there is no reason to declare the method in a private interface
- (void)loadRequestFromString:(NSString*)urlString;
{ 
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}
```

As this is implementation code it shouldn't exist in the interface.